# PHP database query failed

Tags: php, sql

```
 <?php
        require_once 'coninc.php';  
        $query_run = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM station") or die('Query failed');   
 ?>
```

I am getting the output as query failed everytime I am trying to refreshing the page. The coninc.php file has no errors. The connection with the database is getting established. The name of the table is correct. Is there anything wrong with the syntax?

Comment: Try changing the `die('Query failed')` to `die(mysql_error())` instead and see if that points you in the right direction. If not, then post the error message. A wild guess would be that you need to quote the table name using backticks instead. Or the obvious choice that there's no table called station in the selected database (or there's no database selected at all).

Comment: What about the database selection? Why don't you use `mysql_error()` to see what the error is?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,remove single '' from table name

```
<?php
        require 'coninc.php';

    $query_run = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM station") or die('Query failed'); 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove ' at table name

```
<?php
        require 'coninc.php';

    $query_run = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM station") or die('Query failed'); 
 ?>
```